# Copy files over to s3 from ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have an FTP running on my ec2 instance and I'll like to move over those files (after some processing) to s3.

Lots of posts on this to either use the Amazon .NET, php or python APIs or use a 3rd party tool like s3cmd. I'd rather use something like s3cmd because I just want to do something right in a bash script.

But I'm wondering if there are any Amazon tools available on the ec2 instance that do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon Linux AMI includes a tool called `s3put`.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but I can't find docs on this. I need to add a prefix to the file. i.e. file is foo.mp4 and I want to upload it so it has a prefix (folder) myfolder/foo.mp4. Do you know if you can do that?

Comment: Just try running it and you'll get the docs. `key_prefix` looks to do what you want.

Comment: hrmm, I don't see that option. It has `prefix` which doesn't look like it and `path` which may do this but doesn't seem to work. Can't even see what version this is.